# Efficiently using 1-D pyfftw on small slices of a 3-D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, pyfftw

I have a 3D data cube of values of size on the order of 10,000x512x512.  I want to parse a window of vectors (say 6) along dim[0] repeatedly and generate the fourier transforms efficiently.  I think I'm doing an array copy into the pyfftw package and it's giving me massive overhead.  I'm going over the documentation now since I think there is an option I need to set, but I could use some extra help on the syntax.

This code was originally written by another person with numpy.fft.rfft and accelerated with numba.  But the implementation wasn't working on my workstation so I re-wrote everything and opted to go for pyfftw instead.

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw as ftw
from tkinter import simpledialog
from math import ceil
import multiprocessing

ftw.config.NUM_THREADS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
ftw.interfaces.cache.enable()

def runme():
    # normally I would load a file, but for Stack Overflow, I'm just going to generate a 3D data cube so I'll delete references to the binary saving/loading functions:
    # load the file
    dataChunk = np.random.random((1000,512,512))
    numFrames = dataChunk.shape[0]
    # select the window size
    windowSize = int(simpledialog.askstring('Window Size',
        'How many frames to demodulate a single time point?'))
    numChannels = windowSize//2+1
    # create fftw arrays
    ftwIn = ftw.empty_aligned(windowSize, dtype='complex128')
    ftwOut = ftw.empty_aligned(windowSize, dtype='complex128')
    fftObject = ftw.FFTW(ftwIn,ftwOut)
    # perform DFT on the data chunk
    demodFrames = dataChunk.shape[0]//windowSize
    channelChunks = np.zeros([numChannels,demodFrames,
        dataChunk.shape[1],dataChunk.shape[2]])
    channelChunks = getDFT(dataChunk,channelChunks,
        ftwIn,ftwOut,fftObject,windowSize,numChannels)
    return channelChunks          

def getDFT(data,channelOut,ftwIn,ftwOut,fftObject,
        windowSize,numChannels):
    frameLen = data.shape[0]
    demodFrames = frameLen//windowSize
    for yy in range(data.shape[1]):
        for xx in range(data.shape[2]):
            index = 0
            for i in range(0,frameLen-windowSize+1,windowSize):
                ftwIn[:] = data[i:i+windowSize,yy,xx]
                fftObject() 
                channelOut[:,index,yy,xx] = 2*np.abs(ftwOut[:numChannels])/windowSize
                index+=1
    return channelOut

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runme()
```

What happens is I get a 4D array; the variable channelChunks.  I am saving out each channel to a binary (not included in the code above, but the saving part works fine).

This process is for a demodulation project we have, the 4D data cube channelChunks is then parsed into eval(numChannel) 3D data cubes (movies) and from that we are able to separate a movie by color given our experimental set up.  I was hoping I could circumvent writing a C++ function that calls the fft on the matrix via pyfftw.

Effectively, I am taking windowSize=6 elements along the 0 axis of dataChunk at a given index of 1 and 2 axis and performing a 1D FFT.  I need to do this throughout the entire 3D volume of dataChunk to generate the demodulated movies.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you profiled this?  That should give you a good idea of where the time is actually being spent.  Writing a C++ function isn't going to speed things up in most cases.

Comment: yeah, I ran cProfiler.  About 98% of the time is spent on the getDFT call.  The issue appears to be in the for loop: for i in range(0,frameLen-windowSize+1,windowSize):   However, the profiler didn't go into more detail so I need to get better statistics, maybe call another option.  Anyway, I think the issue is inside the for loop at the line ftwIn[:] = data[i:i+windowSize,yy,xx] .  It's taking 40 minutes for 10,000 frames in axis0, I'm positive I can get 1-2 orders of magnitude improvement if the memory was managed properly.

Comment: `cProfiler.run` should provide the time spent on every function call made - it's just a matter of understanding what's there.  The function `getDFT` is most obvious because it loops, causing it to take a long time compared to everything else.  You can probably replace the loops over `xx` and `yy` with an `axis` argument in the fft function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The [FFTW advanced plans](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs) can  be automatically built by pyfftw.**
The code could be modified in the following way:

- **Real to complex transforms** can be used instead of complex to complex transform.
  Using pyfftw, it typically writes:

  ```
  ftwIn = ftw.empty_aligned(windowSize, dtype='float64')
  ftwOut = ftw.empty_aligned(windowSize//2+1, dtype='complex128')
  fftObject = ftw.FFTW(ftwIn,ftwOut)
  ```
- Add a few **flags to the FFTW planner**. For instance, **`FFTW_MEASURE`** will time different algorithms and pick the best. **`FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT`** signals that the input array can be modified: some implementations tricks can be used.

  ```
  fftObject = ftw.FFTW(ftwIn,ftwOut, flags=('FFTW_MEASURE','FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',))
  ```
- Limit the number of divisions. A division costs more than a multiplication.

  ```
  scale=1.0/windowSize
  for ...
      for ...
          2*np.abs(ftwOut[:,:,:])*scale  #instead of /windowSize
  ```
- **Avoid multiple for loops by making use of [FFTW advanced plan](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs) through pyfftw.**

  ```
  nbwindow=numFrames//windowSize
  # create fftw arrays
  ftwIn = ftw.empty_aligned((nbwindow,windowSize,dataChunk.shape[2]), dtype='float64')
  ftwOut = ftw.empty_aligned((nbwindow,windowSize//2+1,dataChunk.shape[2]), dtype='complex128')
  fftObject = ftw.FFTW(ftwIn,ftwOut, axes=(1,), flags=('FFTW_MEASURE','FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',))

  ...
  for yy in range(data.shape[1]):
      ftwIn[:] = np.reshape(data[0:nbwindow*windowSize,yy,:],(nbwindow,windowSize,data.shape[2]),order='C')
      fftObject()
      channelOut[:,:,yy,:]=np.transpose(2*np.abs(ftwOut[:,:,:])*scale, (1,0,2))
  ```

Here is the modifed code. I also, decreased the number of frame to 100, set the seed of the random generator to check that the outcome is not modifed and commented tkinter. **The size of the window can be set to a power of two**, or a number made by multiplying 2,3,5 or 7, so that the Cooley-Tuckey algorithm can be efficiently applied. Avoid large prime numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw as ftw
#from tkinter import simpledialog
from math import ceil
import multiprocessing
import time


ftw.config.NUM_THREADS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
ftw.interfaces.cache.enable()
ftw.config.PLANNER_EFFORT = 'FFTW_MEASURE'

def runme():
    # normally I would load a file, but for Stack Overflow, I'm just going to generate a 3D data cube so I'll delete references to the binary saving/loading functions:
    # load the file
    np.random.seed(seed=42)
    dataChunk = np.random.random((100,512,512))
    numFrames = dataChunk.shape[0]
    # select the window size
    #windowSize = int(simpledialog.askstring('Window Size',
    #    'How many frames to demodulate a single time point?'))
    windowSize=32
    numChannels = windowSize//2+1

    nbwindow=numFrames//windowSize
    # create fftw arrays
    ftwIn = ftw.empty_aligned((nbwindow,windowSize,dataChunk.shape[2]), dtype='float64')
    ftwOut = ftw.empty_aligned((nbwindow,windowSize//2+1,dataChunk.shape[2]), dtype='complex128')

    #ftwIn = ftw.empty_aligned(windowSize, dtype='complex128')
    #ftwOut = ftw.empty_aligned(windowSize, dtype='complex128')
    fftObject = ftw.FFTW(ftwIn,ftwOut, axes=(1,), flags=('FFTW_MEASURE','FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',))
    # perform DFT on the data chunk
    demodFrames = dataChunk.shape[0]//windowSize
    channelChunks = np.zeros([numChannels,demodFrames,
        dataChunk.shape[1],dataChunk.shape[2]])
    channelChunks = getDFT(dataChunk,channelChunks,
        ftwIn,ftwOut,fftObject,windowSize,numChannels)
    return channelChunks          

def getDFT(data,channelOut,ftwIn,ftwOut,fftObject,
        windowSize,numChannels):
    frameLen = data.shape[0]
    demodFrames = frameLen//windowSize
    printed=0
    nbwindow=data.shape[0]//windowSize
    scale=1.0/windowSize
    for yy in range(data.shape[1]):
        #for xx in range(data.shape[2]):
            index = 0

            ftwIn[:] = np.reshape(data[0:nbwindow*windowSize,yy,:],(nbwindow,windowSize,data.shape[2]),order='C')
            fftObject()
            channelOut[:,:,yy,:]=np.transpose(2*np.abs(ftwOut[:,:,:])*scale, (1,0,2))
            #for i in range(nbwindow):
                #channelOut[:,i,yy,xx] = 2*np.abs(ftwOut[i,:])*scale

            if printed==0:
                      for j in range(channelOut.shape[0]):
                          print j,channelOut[j,0,yy,0]
                      printed=1

    return channelOut

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seconds=time.time()
    runme()
    print "time: ", time.time()-seconds
```

Let us know how much it speeds up your computations! I went from 24s to less than 2s on my computer...

Comment: Oh yeah, it's at least an order of magnitude faster, I processed 10K frames in a few minutes vs. the hour it took before.  I have to do a little more stuff on my end because I'm loading data sets of arbitrary length, so the last data chunk needs a new ftw object call with its data size.  I'll put up some stats up on Tuesday.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I checked the cprofiler output.  So the actual pyfft call is only taking me 36 seconds for 10,000 frames at a window size of 6, total execution time of 237 seconds.  Before it took me 2001 seconds for everything, with about 1800 seconds spent at the looped DFT calls.  My overhead is now in loading the data -- which is easy to fix.  Thanks again!